# Is there a way to undo workspace chaining?

Tags: catkin, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

From my $ROS_PACKAGE_PATH, I realised my workspaces have been chained together. Is there a way to undo it?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/297782/is-there-a-way-to-undo-workspace-chaining?/) by [amelia](https://answers.ros.org/users/35848/amelia/) on ROS Answers with karma: 18 on 2018-07-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

for `catkin_make`:

- Delete `build`, `devel` and `install`.
- Source `/opt/ros/kinetic/setup.bash`
- `catkin_make`

for `catkin_tools`:

- `catkin clean --yes` (essentially the same as above)
- `catkin config --extend /opt/ros/<DISTRO>`
- `catkin build`

---

Originally posted by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) with karma: 12390 on 2018-07-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [amelia](https://answers.ros.org/users/35848/amelia/) on 2018-07-18**:
THANK YOU SO MUCH!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!